# groff in chroot environment

Tags: environment, chroot, groff

I want to use groff in a chroot environment. It bombs out with "Abort trap" which is not very helpful as an error message. I assume it is invoking some tool or data it can't reach. I can run the same command outside the chroot environment without issue - other than security risk.

Is there a debug mode I can use to get a trace of what is being called?

Where can I get a list of what needs to be copied into the chroot environment?

Comment: You could using strace and ltrace to see what it is trying to do.

Comment: Those are Linux tools and I am using OpenBSD

Comment: OpenBSD seems to have [ktrace](https://man.openbsd.org/ktrace.1) which seems to be able to show system calls.